# Entity Framework in disconnected scenario throws saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I am working in a small project using Web API, and entity Framework. And I facing some issue in posting my entity.

My entities look like this:

```
 public class DayExercises
    {
        public DayExercises()
        {
            Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Day { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }

    }
```

and my `Exercise` entity look like this.

```
 public class Exercise 
    {    
       public Exercise()
        {
            DayExercises = new List<DayExercises>();
        }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual List<DayExercises> DayExercises { get; set; }
    }
```

and my web api method for posting the `dayExercises` look like this

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(WorkoutTemplate))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostWorkoutTemplate(DayExercises dayExercises)
    {            
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        foreach (var dayExercise in dayExercises)
        {
            fitnessDbContext.Entry(dayExercise).State = EntityState.Added;

            foreach (var exercise in dayExercise.Exercises.ToList())
            {
                fitnessDbContext.Entry(exercise).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

            }
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = dayExercises.Id }, dayExercises);
    }
```

The relationship is Many-To-Many.

**Problem:**
I am sending a `dayExercise` with existing `Exercise`(already existing in database) to my method. but when I'm posting `dayExercise` with SAME two exercises. it throw that exception:

*Additional information: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'FitnessFirst.WebApi.Exercise' have the same primary key value.
 Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model.
 Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.*

I also tried to `Deattach` the entities, and Get the exercise from Database using their `ID` and `Attach` them again and add it to the `dayExercise` but it doesn't save to database.

NOTE: when I add two different exercises, it doesn't throw that Exception.

I also read the following answers, but it doesn't solve it: [Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372936/ensure-that-explicitly-set-primary-key-values-are-unique)

Any Suggestion or explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I ran into the same issue yesterday. This is the solution I came up with. Basically entity framework change tracker only allows unique values for an entity. So to get around the error you need to check if the entity already exists in the change tracker and use that instance.

```
var excercises = dayExercise.Exercises.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < excercises.Count; i++)
{
    var unchangedEntity = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Exercise>()
         .Where(xy => xy.State == EntityState.Unchanged &&
         xy.Entity.Id == excercises [i].Id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (unchangedEntity == null)
    {
        fitnessDbContext.Entry(excercises[i]).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
    else
    {
        excercises[i] = unchangedEntity.Entity;
    }

}
```

Comment: HAHA, ya this is a very old post, I reached to this solution 1 year ago. +1 because you are right.